# Como armazenar um operador?

Tags: python, operadores

Eu gostaria de saber se tem alguma maneira de guardar um operador em uma variável, por exemplo

```
a = <

if 5 a 5:
    pass
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Tem uma forma análoga, utilizando a biblioteca [`operator`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html). Para o operador de menor, existe a função `lt`.

```
from operator import lt

a = lt

if a(4, 5):
    print('4 é menor que 5')
else:
    print('4 é maior ou igual a 5')
```

<sup>Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/@acwoss/EcstaticYellowZeren) | [Ideone](https://ideone.com/hMd87t)</sup>

A partir disso, você pode [montar um mapa](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#mapping-operators-to-functions) que relaciona o texto com o operador e a respectiva função da biblioteca.

Por exemplo, com o trecho de código abaixo é possível informar qualquer uma das quatro operações básicas para ser realizada nos operandos 2 e 3.

```
from operator import add, truediv, mul, sub

OPERATORS = {'+': add, '-': sub, '*': mul, '/': truediv}

while True:
  operator_text = input("Qual operação realizar entre 2 e 3? [+-*/] ")
  try:
    operator = OPERATORS[operator_text]
    print('Resultado de 2 {} 3 = {}'.format(operator_text, operator(2, 3)))
  except KeyError:
    break
```

Veja funcionando no [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/PopularWiryNewsaggregator)

Se preferir utilizar estruturas condicionais, você pode montar vários `if`:

```
if operator == '+':
    resultado = a + b
elif operator == '-':
    resultado = a - b
elif operator == '*':
    resultado = a * b
elif operator == '/':
    resultado = a / b
...
```

Fica mais simples para alguns, mas eu particularmente não gosto pela repetição de código que essa forma apresenta.

Mesmo assim, nenhuma das soluções acima é perfeita, pois veja que em nenhum momento tratamos a quantidade de operandos que cada operador possui. Tratamos todos eles como operadores binários (dois operandos), o que não inclui, por exemplo, a mudança de sinal.  Nem sempre isso será um problema, pois é fácil implementar de forma que o sinal de negativo seja considerado junto com o operando.

Answer (score 4):

De maneira alternativa você poderia usar lambdas para isso. A ideia seria basicamente fazer a implementação da biblioteca `operators` que o [@AndersonCarlosWoss](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/5878/anderson-carlos-woss) [mencionou em sua resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/275823/64969).

A vantagem de se usar lambdas seria permitir operadores binários generalizados. A desvantagem é que a implementação na biblioteca dos operadores que ela provê é muito provavelmente melhor do que a sua.

```
# para a operação de comparação
op = lambda(a, b): a < b

if op(5, 5):
  pass

# para a operação de potenciação 
op = lambda (a, b) : a**b

print(op(2, 3))
```